# C: inet_ntop return value position?

Tags: c, libpcap, inet, inet-ntop

I am reviewing the `inet_ntop` documentation.   Typically, string builder operations in `C` return either a pointer to the end of the string, or an integer indicating the length of the string written.

The documentation of `inet_ntop` states quite ambiguously:

```
On success, inet_ntop() returns a non-null pointer to dst.  NULL is 
returned if there was an error, with the errno set to indicate the 
error.
```

There are two problems here:

1. Null string termination: it is not clear whether I need to add a null string delimiter throughout the memory allocation where `inet_ntop` is printing when compiling at order 3 or more
2. I do not know whether the output of the function returns a pointer to the last written character, or the first written character.

---

What does `inet_ntop` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite clear to me, but perhaps you need to apply some "good will" to get it:

1. It's not a string in C if it isn't terminated, so of course the result is terminated.
2. `dst` is an input argument, even if it's a bit weirdly written "a pointer to `dst`" can't be "a pointer to `dst` plus something".

You can of course also [read an implementation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/resolv/inet_ntop.c.html) to see what's going on. The last statement for the "happy path" (no buffer overflow) for both IPv4 and v6 variants is:

```
return strcpy(dst, tmp);
```

Which instantly tells you that `dst` is receiving a terminated string, and that `dst` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

It returns `const char *` and since the `dst` parameter is required to be a valid object (you can not pass `NULL` as `dst`) there is no need to create an intermediate pointer to return the status of the function.

Comment: It returns `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`inet_pton()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_pton.html):

> ...
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <arpa/inet.h>
>
> const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *restrict src,
>        char *restrict dst, socklen_t size);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `inet_ntop()` function shall convert a numeric address into a text
>   string suitable for presentation. The af argument shall specify the
>   family of the address. This can be `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.  The src
>   argument points to a buffer holding an IPv4 address if the `af`
>   argument is `AF_INET`,   or an IPv6 address if the `af` argument is
>   `AF_INET6`;  the address must be in network byte order. The `dst`
>   argument points to a buffer where the function stores the resulting
>   text string; it shall not be `NULL`. The size argument specifies the
>   size of this buffer, which shall be large enough to hold the text
>   string (`INET_ADDRSTRLEN` characters for IPv4, `INET6_ADDRSTRLEN`
>   characters for IPv6).
>
> ...
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `inet_ntop()` function shall return a pointer to the buffer
>   containing the text string if the conversion succeeds, and `NULL`
>   otherwise, and set `errno` to indicate the error.
>
> ...
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> The `inet_ntop()` and `inet_pton()` functions shall fail if:
>
> [`EAFNOSUPPORT`] The `af` argument is invalid.
>
> [`ENOSPC`] The size of the `inet_ntop()` result buffer is inadequate.

And [the definition of a "string"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_92):

> **3.92 Character String**
>
> A contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the
>   first null byte.

Given that, the answer to

> 1. Null string termination: it is not clear whether I need to add a null string delimiter throughout the memory allocation where inet_ntop is printing when compiling at order 3 or more

should be clear.  A string **by definition** includes the null byte.  `inet_pton()` returns a pointer to a buffer that contains such a string.  No addition of a null byte is needed.

And the answer to

> 2. I do not know whether the output of the function returns a pointer to the last written character, or the first written character.

is given by the C standard in [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7):

> ... When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.

So, the "pointer to the buffer containing the text string if the conversion succeeds" returned by `inet_ntop()`  points to the first byte in the string.

Comment: You have not dealt with broken C code much, I take it.  Nonetheless, I see this question is going to trigger a stack overflow "hammer session"

Comment: flagged.  I get it, I promise: a string is a null delimeted char array.  but these are not always null delimited by a human user, or function.  I'm not saying I do it.  But look: we write computer languages in computing language because English is imprecise.  You are in denial over this simple fact, and blasting away on a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: Standards are written for implementors, not for users.  Reference documentation like the `inet_ntop` manpage is written for people who already know all the ins and outs of the language and just need a reminder.  Quoting such documents at someone who does not fully understand C yet, not only fails to answer their question, it teaches them that people who don't fully understand C are not welcome here.  Kindly do not do this ever again.

Comment: @donlan No, you **DON'T** get it: *a string is a null delimeted char array. but these are not always null delimited.*  It's not a "string" if it's missing the null character termination.  The English here is not imprecise, you are.

Comment: @zwol *Standards are written for implementors* Writing code **is** implementing, and the standards are the reference. The POSIX standard is clearer than what I assume to be the Linux man page quoted in the question.  I started with `inet_pton()` in POSIX, pulled in the POSIX string definition, and got to the point of answering his questions simply and directly from the relevant standards.  It's a simple, direct answer in a way that demonstrated **where** it comes from.  Care to explain what's wrong with that?

Comment: No, you have just misinterpretation my English: strings *are* null delimited. However, *students* may record strings in buffers that automatically get nulled at standard compilation orders, but yield memory faults at order 3 compilation and beyond.  I encounter it all the time when I come in and clean up code.  Thus, I am very wary of all the crazy things that can happen.

Comment: @donlan Your question isn't about student-written code.  It's about `inet_ntop()`, a widely-used, standard library function.

Comment: In other words: char arrays that are incompletely filled default to being strings at low compilation orders.  However, I must go in and correct memory leaks and read faults if, say, a string was not technically created, but rather a char array with no null delimitation.  So you may very well not be experienced with broken C code, and my point may very well be astute.

Comment: @donlan Then make it clear you're dealing with such data.  Your question is literally *What does inet_ntop return?*

Comment: You can’t desperately cry foul because I didn’t provide a memoir of context to the question.  The Stack overflow code is minimal content needed for the question, and answer.  I asked a question, and received an answer.  But it seems you want to use this to get some kind of positive emotional transaction regarding your intellect.  I am sure you are very bright.  But I don’t have time for this.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I feel like I'm repeating myself here, but lemme try to put it clearer: Your answer is NOT a simple, direct answer. For anyone who does not already know how to read the style of documentation you are quoting, it is _totally incomprehensible_. Moreover, anyone who knows how to read this style of documentation _necessarily_ knows C well enough that they wouldn't have asked the question you're answering. Therefore your answer is not only useless, it's _hostile_. You are implying that no one who can't already read this documentation deserves to be allowed to ask questions here.